# Deserialize a json string to an object in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following string

```
{"action":"print","method":"onData","data":"Madan Mohan"}
```

I Want to deserialize to a object of class

```
class payload
    string action
    string method
    string data
```

I am using python 2.6 and 2.7

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
>>> j = '{"action": "print", "method": "onData", "data": "Madan Mohan"}'
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> class Payload(object):
...     def __init__(self, j):
...         self.__dict__ = json.loads(j)
... 
>>> p = Payload(j)
>>>
>>> p.action
'print'
>>> p.method
'onData'
>>> p.data
'Madan Mohan'
```

Comment: If that helps anyone, in my opinion, the only right solution is a library. Not custom made serialization. See [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)

Comment: For a class with existing members, don't assign `__dict__` like this. You will lose existing members if they aren't in the json string. If you have to do it, use `self.__dict__.update(otherdict)`

Comment: `self.__dict__.update(j)` breaks the object if there are `@property`s defined. I recommend `[setattr(obj, key, val) for key, val in j.items() if hasattr(obj, key)]` with `obj` being the object to be updated and `j` the json dict

Answer (score 61):

To elaborate on Sami's answer:

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
class Payload(object):
    def __init__(self, action, method, data):
        self.action = action
        self.method = method
        self.data = data

import json

def as_payload(dct):
    return Payload(dct['action'], dct['method'], dct['data'])

payload = json.loads(message, object_hook = as_payload)
```

My objection to the

```
.__dict__
```

solution is that while it does the job and is concise, the Payload class becomes totally *generic* - it doesn't document its fields.

For example, if the Payload message had an unexpected format, instead of throwing a key not found error when the Payload was created, no error would be generated until the payload was used.

Comment: my 2 cents, replace `return Payload(dct['action'], dct['method'], dct['data'])` with `return Payload(dct.get('action', None), dct.get('method', None), dct.get('data', None))` to allow some of the fields to be optional.

Answer (score 18):

In recent versions of python, you can use [marshmallow-dataclass](https://pypi.org/project/marshmallow-dataclass):

```py
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass

@dataclass
class Payload
    action:str
    method:str
    data:str

Payload.Schema().load({"action":"print","method":"onData","data":"Madan Mohan"})
```

Comment: This seems the most convenient way.

Comment: Thank you ! It's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: does this support nested jsons like arrays of dictionary or dictionary of dictionaries?

Answer (score 17):

If you are embracing the type hints in Python 3.6, you can do it like this:

```
def from_json(data, cls):
    annotations: dict = cls.__annotations__ if hasattr(cls, '__annotations__') else None
    if issubclass(cls, List):
        list_type = cls.__args__[0]
        instance: list = list()
        for value in data:
            instance.append(from_json(value, list_type))
        return instance
    elif issubclass(cls, Dict):
            key_type = cls.__args__[0]
            val_type = cls.__args__[1]
            instance: dict = dict()
            for key, value in data.items():
                instance.update(from_json(key, key_type), from_json(value, val_type))
            return instance
    else:
        instance : cls = cls()
        for name, value in data.items():
            field_type = annotations.get(name)
            if inspect.isclass(field_type) and isinstance(value, (dict, tuple, list, set, frozenset)):
                setattr(instance, name, from_json(value, field_type))
            else:
                setattr(instance, name, value)
        return instance
```

Which then allows you do instantiate typed objects like this:

```
class Bar:
    value : int

class Foo:
    x : int
    bar : List[Bar]


obj : Foo = from_json(json.loads('{"x": 123, "bar":[{"value": 3}, {"value": 2}, {"value": 1}]}'), Foo)
print(obj.x)
print(obj.bar[2].value)
```

This syntax requires Python 3.6 though and does not cover all cases - for example, support for typing.Any... But at least it does not pollute the classes that need to be deserialized with extra init/tojson methods.

Comment: This fails at python 3.7 annotations.get(name) no longer returns GenericMeta

Answer (score 12):

I thought I lose all my hairs for solving this 'challenge'. I faced following problems:

1. How to deserialize nested objects, lists etc.
2. I like constructors with specified fields
3. I don't like dynamic fields
4. I don't like hacky solutions

I found a library called `jsonpickle` which is has proven to be really useful.

Installation:

```
pip install jsonpickle
```

Here is a code example with writing nested objects to file:

```py
import jsonpickle


class SubObject:
    def __init__(self, sub_name, sub_age):
        self.sub_name = sub_name
        self.sub_age = sub_age


class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, name, age, sub_object):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sub_object = sub_object


john_junior = SubObject("John jr.", 2)

john = TestClass("John", 21, john_junior)

file_name = 'JohnWithSon' + '.json'

john_string = jsonpickle.encode(john)

with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(john_string)

john_from_file = open(file_name).read()

test_class_2 = jsonpickle.decode(john_from_file)

print(test_class_2.name)
print(test_class_2.age)
print(test_class_2.sub_object.sub_name)
```

Output:

```
John
21
John jr.
```

Website: http://jsonpickle.github.io/

Hope it will save your time (and hairs).

Comment: Does it supports validation ? also type hints ?

Comment: @AnumSheraz not really. I believe the resulting object is still dynamic and it can be hard to obtain the original type. I think that [`marshmallow-dataclass`](https://pypi.org/project/marshmallow-dataclass/) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852458/3873799) is a better solution.

Answer (score 11):

[pydantic](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/) is an increasingly popular library for python 3.6+ projects. It mainly does data validation and settings management using type hints.

A basic example using different types:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ClassicBar(BaseModel):
    count_drinks: int
    is_open: bool
 
data = {'count_drinks': '226', 'is_open': 'False'}
cb = ClassicBar(**data)
>>> cb
ClassicBar(count_drinks=226, is_open=False)
```

What I love about the lib is that you get a lot of goodies for free, like

```
>>> cb.json()
'{"count_drinks": 226, "is_open": false}'
>>> cb.dict()
{'count_drinks': 226, 'is_open': False}
```

Comment: supports nested json?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to save lines of code and leave the most flexible solution, we can deserialize the json string to a dynamic object:

```python
p = lambda:None
p.__dict__ = json.loads('{"action": "print", "method": "onData", "data": "Madan Mohan"}')
```

>>>> p.action 
 
output: u'print'

>>>> p.method
output: u'onData'

Comment: This is tantalizingly close, but doesn't handle nested JSON.  `p.__dict__ = json.loads('{"parent":{"child":{"name":"henry"}}}')` still requires accessing child like a dict.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to add some checking of the fields, e.g. so you can catch errors like when you get invalid json, or not the json you were expecting, so I used namedtuples:

```
from collections import namedtuple
payload = namedtuple('payload', ['action', 'method', 'data'])
def deserialize_payload(json):
    kwargs =  dict([(field, json[field]) for field in payload._fields]) 
    return payload(**kwargs)
```

this will let give you nice errors when the json you are parsing does not match the thing you want it to parse

```
>>> json = {"action":"print","method":"onData","data":"Madan Mohan"}
>>> deserialize_payload(json)
payload(action='print', method='onData', data='Madan Mohan')
>>> badjson = {"error":"404","info":"page not found"}
>>> deserialize_payload(badjson)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in deserialize_payload
KeyError: 'action'
```

if you want to parse nested relations, e.g. `'{"parent":{"child":{"name":"henry"}}}'`
you can still use the namedtuples, and even a more reusable function

```
Person = namedtuple("Person", ['parent'])
Parent = namedtuple("Parent", ['child'])
Child = namedtuple('Child', ['name'])
def deserialize_json_to_namedtuple(json, namedtuple):
    return namedtuple(**dict([(field, json[field]) for field in namedtuple._fields]))

def deserialize_person(json):
     json['parent']['child']  = deserialize_json_to_namedtuple(json['parent']['child'], Child)
     json['parent'] =  deserialize_json_to_namedtuple(json['parent'], Parent) 
     person = deserialize_json_to_namedtuple(json, Person)
     return person
```

giving  you

```
>>> deserialize_person({"parent":{"child":{"name":"henry"}}})
Person(parent=Parent(child=Child(name='henry')))
>>> deserialize_person({"error":"404","info":"page not found"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in deserialize_person
KeyError: 'parent'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to simply pass the json string as a dict to the constructor of your object. For example your object is:

```
class Payload(object):
    def __init__(self, action, method, data, *args, **kwargs):
        self.action = action
        self.method = method
        self.data = data
```

And the following two lines of python code will construct it:

```
j = json.loads(yourJsonString)
payload = Payload(**j)
```

Basically, we first create a generic json object from the json string. Then, we pass the generic json object as a dict to the constructor of the Payload class. The constructor of Payload class interprets the dict as keyword arguments and sets all the appropriate fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can specialize an encoder for object creation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
import json
class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, complex):
            return {"real": obj.real,
            "imag": obj.imag,
            "__class__": "complex"}
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

print json.dumps(2 + 1j, cls=ComplexEncoder)
```

Comment: please don't only paste the links on answers, as it can go down anytime. Give nutshell answer from that link here too.

Comment: this question is about decoding not encoding, so this doesn't help at all

Answer (score 1):

While [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826012/6687477) answer points us to a good technique, the implementation that he gave runs into a problem when we have nested objects.

```
class more_info
    string status

class payload
    string action
    string method
    string data
    class more_info
```

with the below code:

```
def as_more_info(dct):
    return MoreInfo(dct['status'])

def as_payload(dct):
    return Payload(dct['action'], dct['method'], dct['data'], as_more_info(dct['more_info']))

payload = json.loads(message, object_hook = as_payload)
```

`payload.more_info` will also be treated as an instance of `payload` which will lead to parsing errors.

From the official docs:

> object_hook is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded (a dict). The return value of object_hook will be used instead of the dict.

Hence, I would prefer to propose the following solution instead:

```
class MoreInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, status):
        self.status = status

    @staticmethod
    def fromJson(mapping):
        if mapping is None:
            return None

        return MoreInfo(
            mapping.get('status')
        )

class Payload(object):
    def __init__(self, action, method, data, more_info):
        self.action = action
        self.method = method
        self.data = data
        self.more_info = more_info

    @staticmethod
    def fromJson(mapping):
        if mapping is None:
            return None

        return Payload(
            mapping.get('action'),
            mapping.get('method'),
            mapping.get('data'),
            MoreInfo.fromJson(mapping.get('more_info'))
        )

import json
def toJson(obj, **kwargs):
    return json.dumps(obj, default=lambda j: j.__dict__, **kwargs)

def fromJson(msg, cls, **kwargs):
    return cls.fromJson(json.loads(msg, **kwargs))

info = MoreInfo('ok')
payload = Payload('print', 'onData', 'better_solution', info)
pl_json = toJson(payload)
l1 = fromJson(pl_json, Payload)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods to deserialize json string to an object. All above methods are acceptable but I suggest using a library to prevent duplicate key issues or serializing/deserializing of nested objects.

[Pykson, is a JSON Serializer and Deserializer for Python](https://github.com/sinarezaei/pykson) which can help you achieve. Simply define Payload class model as JsonObject then use Pykson to convert json string to object.

```
from pykson import Pykson, JsonObject, StringField

class Payload(pykson.JsonObject):
    action = StringField()
    method = StringField()
    data = StringField()

json_text = '{"action":"print","method":"onData","data":"Madan Mohan"}'
payload = Pykson.from_json(json_text, Payload)
```