# Can I deserialize Json to class like C# Newtonsoft in Python

Tags: python, json, class, serialization, json.net

This is json

```
{"name":"david","age":14,"gender":"male"}
```

This is python class

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.age = None
        self.gener = None
        self.language = None
```

this is Code

```
#deserialize func~~~~~
print person.name #prints david
print person.age #prints 14
print person.gender #prints male
print person.language #prints "None"
```

Can I deserialize Json to class in Python(like C# Newtonsoft)

Thank you.

Comment: It's been tackled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476983/deserialize-a-json-string-to-an-object-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize a json string to an object in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476983/deserialize-a-json-string-to-an-object-in-python)

Comment: I want to matching all json item, like person. language is None
from this json
{"name":"david","age":14,"gender":"male"}

Comment: @ambitiousdh If you don't want the None values do a dictionary comprehension and remove all attributes that are None i.e `{k: v for k, v in self.__dict__ if v}`

Comment: No, I want to do mapping even if it is not in json Item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it with the `json.loads()` method.  You would also need to ensure your JSON was a string and not just declared inline.

Here's an example program:

```
import json

js = '{"name":"david","age":14,"gender":"male"}'

class Person:
    def __init__(self, json_def):
        self.__dict__ = json.loads(json_def)

person = Person(js)

print person.name
print person.age
print person.gender
```

Just a note, though.  When you attempt to use `print person.language` you will have an error, since it doesn't exist on the class.

**EDIT**

If there is a direct mapping desired, it would require explicit mapping of each possible object.

The following example will give each property a value if it exists in the JSON object and also solves the desire to use any missing properties:

```
import json

js = '{"name":"david","age":14,"gender":"male"}'

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, json_def):
        s = json.loads(json_def)
        self.name = None if 'name' not in s else s['name']
        self.age = None if 'age' not in s else s['age']
        self.gender = None if 'gender' not in s else s['gender']
        self.language = None if 'language' not in s else s['language']

person = Person(js)

print person.name
print person.age
print person.gender
print person.language
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **kwargs like approach when we loads a json we will get a dict
then we can just initialize our object with **json_def and get our object.
for more complex json deserialization you will have to check the dict and take only the values that you need.

example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name=None, age=None, gender=None, language=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.language = language


js = '{"name": "david", "age": 14, "gender": "male"}'
person = Person(**json.loads(js))
print(person.name)
js = '{"name": "david", "age": 14, "gender": "male", "language": "English"}'
person = Person(**json.loads(js))
print(person.language)
```