# Method/Library in Python which is similar to NewtonSoft in C#

Tags: python, c#, json

I am trying to do something similar in Python like `NewtonSoft` is doing in `C#`.

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "lead": {
        "Id": "abc",
        "CreateDate": "2020-16-04T17:55:47.229554",
        "Source": "Source"
    },
    "cars": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Year": "1951",
            "Make": "Willys"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Year": "1950"
        }
    ],
    "Client": {
        "LeadId": "ca5326c1fa14475ea6e8106c8c4a3d9d",
        "FirstName": "Christopher",
        "LastName": "Murphy"
    }
}
```

If I serialize the JSON and use `NewtonSoft` in `C#` then I get the following result:

```
"{\"lead\":{\"Id\":\"abc\",\"CreateDate\":\"2020-16-04T17:55:47.229554\",\"Source\":\"Source\"},\"cars\":[{\"Id\":1,\"Year\":\"1951\",\"Make\":\"Willys\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Year\":\"1950\"}],\"Client\":{\"LeadId\":\"ca5326c1fa14475ea6e8106c8c4a3d9d\",\"FirstName\":\"Christopher\",\"LastName\":\"Murphy\"}}"
```

But the `dump` and `dumps` methods are giving other results in Python, Is there other way to achieve the same result in python?

Comment: What is different about the output from Python?

Comment: Something similar is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596710/can-i-deserialize-json-to-class-like-c-sharp-newtonsoft-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476983/deserialize-a-json-string-to-an-object-in-python)

Comment: *But the dump and dumps methods are giving other results in Python* - then please [edit] your question to include the code that doesn't work -- i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO!  Why do you need it in that format?  If you 100% want it exactly like that, you could write 1-20 lines of code that make it that way; something like `with open(json_fname, 'r') as f: json_lines=f.readlines(); out=''; for line in lines: out+=line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are no weird edge cases I'm unaware of, you could do something like this

```
def serialize(json_fname):
  with open(json_fname, 'r') as f:
    json_lines=f.readlines()

  out=''
  for line in json_lines:
    out+=line
  out=out.replace(' ','')
  return out.replace('\n','')

serialized=serialize('myjson.json')

#  Later in the program:
#    do(serialized)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped, but what I meant is when in C# you use NewtonSoft, then it automatically inserts this backslashes "\". E.g "{\"lead\":{\"Id\":\"abc\"..., do you know is there anything similar in Python?

Comment: Actually, after inserting this part to code and adding the dump method as a file, I got the desired result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, misunderstood the question. What you need is to escape the serialized string with replace or other method.

Also, there may be some differences between the object's real value, and the value you see when using debug tools or depending on the IDE.