# Transform c sharp code to python Class usage

Tags: python, c#

I m not familiar with python and I want to convert below code from C# to python

```
 Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse)
    public class StatisticsItem
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string home { get; set; }
        public string away { get; set; }
        public int compareCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public string groupName { get; set; }
        public List<StatisticsItem> statisticsItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class Statistic
    {
        public string period { get; set; }
        public List<Group> groups { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Statistic> statistics { get; set; }
    }
```

the aim is to convert a JSON flat file to an object i m able to do it with C# but I had some difficulty to do it in python

Comment: if your aim is to convert a json file to an object, you might want to use the json module (json.load function)

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use `__dict__` properties in the class.

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), as well as a previous [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15477213/14833748) for more detail.